# SKShapeNode and CGPathRef EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skshapenode, cgpathref

I am trying to dynamically draw curves along a path in an attempt to represent mountains.

I have a function that returns a `CGPathRef`, which is a C pointer to a struct.

```
-(CGPathRef)newPath
{
    CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    //inserting quad curves, etc
    return mutablePath;
}
```

I then pass these `CGPathRefs` around by wrapping them in a `UIBezierPath`.

```
-(NSArray*)otherFunction
{
    CGPathRef ref = [self newPath];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath: ref];
    NSArray* paths = @[path];
    CGPathRelease(ref);
    return paths;
}
```

I then take the returned array of paths and display them to the screen using an `SKShapeNode`.

```
SKShapeNode *node = [SKShapeNode new];

NSArray* paths = [self otherFunction];
CGPathRef ref = [[paths firstObject] CGPath];

node.path = ref; 
node.fillColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
node.lineWidth = 2;
```

And finally.

```
[self addChild:node];
CGPathRelease(node.path);
```

After I repeat this sequence of action a few times my program breaks and shows me.

> UIApplicationMain with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2.

I understand there is a memory leak.

My question is how do I handle releasing the `CGPathRef` when I end up passing it through a few functions and wrapping it in another class?

I updated the code and am now receiving a EXC_I386_GPFLT error.

Comment: I suggest you post the actual code that compiles instead of "path from otherFunction unwrapped."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems.

1. I'm not very familiar with `SKShapeNode`, but from the documentation it looks like it just uses the path you give it without copying it (unlike `UIBezierPath`).  In that case, you need to copy the path out of the `UIBezierPath`'s `CGPathRef`, because otherwise it will be deallocated once the `UIBezierPath` is released.  For example:

   ```
   SKShapeNode *node = [SKShapeNode new];
   CGPathRef pathCopy = CGPathCreateCopy(/* path from other function unwrapped */);
   node.path = pathCopy;
   ...
   ```

   You may possibly need to deallocate that path when you're done with the shape node:

   ```
   CGPathRelease(node.path);
   ```
2. It looks like you have some memory leaks in the code you posted: you're creating `CGPathRef`s in `newPath`, copying them to a `UIBezierPath` in `otherFunction`, and never deleting them.  That would not cause your problem, but it may cause others down the road. :)
3. I'd be careful naming methods with a prefix of `new` since that has some meaning to Objective-C (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308162/property-name-starting-with-new-prefix-leads-to-bad-access-error-in-ios)).  Try `createPath` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with the compiler is if you name a function with newXXX you need to manage your memory. So in the -otherFunction

```
-(NSArray*)otherFunction
{
    CGPathRef ref = [self newPath];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath: ref];
    NSArray* paths = @[path];
    return paths;
}
```

after creating the UIBezierPath, you should call

```
CGPathRelease(ref);
```